# Parsing array of JSON objects into individual documents

Tags: json, go, sarama

I am collecting logs generated by an agent. It generates one large JSON output which I need to decompose into smaller JSON documents and use sarama to write to kafka. Due to MAX size constraint of kafka message, I have problems in demposing into several individual JSON documents. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. The log messages do not have any fixed fields or data types except date/time field indicating of logactivity

Sample #1

```
[{"date":1596206786.847531,"rand_value":11885153394315023285},{"date":1596206787.847446,"rand_value":6208802038498064748},{"date":1596206788.847526,"rand_value":932964293334035461},{"date":1596206789.847568,"rand_value":13217490172547025909}]
```

Sample 2

```
[{"date":1596206786.847743,"cpu_p":0,"user_p":0,"system_p":0,"cpu0.p_cpu":0,"cpu0.p_user":0,"cpu0.p_system":0,"cpu1.p_cpu":0,"cpu1.p_user":0,"cpu1.p_system":0,"cpu2.p_cpu":0,"cpu2.p_user":0,"cpu2.p_system":0,"cpu3.p_cpu":0,"cpu3.p_user":0,"cpu3.p_system":0,"cpu4.p_cpu":0,"cpu4.p_user":0,"cpu4.p_system":0,"cpu5.p_cpu":0,"cpu5.p_user":0,"cpu5.p_system":0,"cpu6.p_cpu":0,"cpu6.p_user":0,"cpu6.p_system":0,"cpu7.p_cpu":0,"cpu7.p_user":0,"cpu7.p_system":0},{"date":1596206787.847689,"cpu_p":1.25,"user_p":0.75,"system_p":0.5,"cpu0.p_cpu":2,"cpu0.p_user":1,"cpu0.p_system":1,"cpu1.p_cpu":1,"cpu1.p_user":0,"cpu1.p_system":1,"cpu2.p_cpu":2,"cpu2.p_user":1,"cpu2.p_system":1,"cpu3.p_cpu":3,"cpu3.p_user":2,"cpu3.p_system":1,"cpu4.p_cpu":1,"cpu4.p_user":0,"cpu4.p_system":1,"cpu5.p_cpu":1,"cpu5.p_user":1,"cpu5.p_system":0,"cpu6.p_cpu":2,"cpu6.p_user":2,"cpu6.p_system":0,"cpu7.p_cpu":0,"cpu7.p_user":0,"cpu7.p_system":0},{"date":1596206788.847754,"cpu_p":0.75,"user_p":0.5,"system_p":0.25,"cpu0.p_cpu":0,"cpu0.p_user":0,"cpu0.p_system":0,"cpu1.p_cpu":1,"cpu1.p_user":0,"cpu1.p_system":1,"cpu2.p_cpu":2,"cpu2.p_user":1,"cpu2.p_system":1,"cpu3.p_cpu":0,"cpu3.p_user":0,"cpu3.p_system":0,"cpu4.p_cpu":0,"cpu4.p_user":0,"cpu4.p_system":0,"cpu5.p_cpu":1,"cpu5.p_user":1,"cpu5.p_system":0,"cpu6.p_cpu":1,"cpu6.p_user":0,"cpu6.p_system":1,"cpu7.p_cpu":1,"cpu7.p_user":0,"cpu7.p_system":1},{"date":1596206789.847805,"cpu_p":0.8750000000000001,"user_p":0.5,"system_p":0.375,"cpu0.p_cpu":1,"cpu0.p_user":0,"cpu0.p_system":1,"cpu1.p_cpu":1,"cpu1.p_user":1,"cpu1.p_system":0,"cpu2.p_cpu":2,"cpu2.p_user":1,"cpu2.p_system":1,"cpu3.p_cpu":0,"cpu3.p_user":0,"cpu3.p_system":0,"cpu4.p_cpu":1,"cpu4.p_user":1,"cpu4.p_system":0,"cpu5.p_cpu":0,"cpu5.p_user":0,"cpu5.p_system":0,"cpu6.p_cpu":2,"cpu6.p_user":2,"cpu6.p_system":0,"cpu7.p_cpu":0,"cpu7.p_user":0,"cpu7.p_system":0}]
```

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)


func main() {

    ibytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile("hello.json")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(-1)
    }

    var msgs []map[string]interface{}

    err = json.Unmarshal(ibytes, &msgs)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Serialization Error", err)
        os.Exit(-1)
    }

    for _,msg:=range msgs {
       fmt.Println("%s",msg)
    }
}
```

I am able to iterate over the individual messages but not in a friendly format to write into kafka.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is your question about how to decompose a large message?

Comment: @BurakSerdar i have updated the question with my sample program

Comment: @BurakSerdar yes my primary problem is decomposing into kafka friendly way retaining the json structure

Comment: What is „Kafka friendly“?

Comment: @Volker i see when i print individual messages no braces or json resemblance. I am using sarama.StringEncoder in construction Producer Message. Thats failing

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find solution by myself using below code

```
var PlaceHolder  []interface{}
    err=json.Unmarshal(dbytes,&PlaceHolder)
    if err!=nil {
       return errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("Error during JSON Unmarshalling (%s) ",err))
        }

    for _,doc:=range PlaceHolder {
        event,_:=json.Marshal(doc)
        if err!=nil{
             log.Println("Skipping: Error during JSON Marshaling (%s) ",err)
         continue
         }
         KafkaMessage:= &sarama.ProducerMessage{
                Topic: this.Topic,
                Value: sarama.StringEncoder(event),
            }
        msgs=append(msgs,KafkaMessage)
    }
```